# Cloud apps and Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-drive-api

I have an a application running on top of AppEngine, and all the data is on the cloud. For the user's point of view, it is like a Google Spreadsheet. The user can "open" a "file" representing his data, update and share. All data is stored at datastore, and not on a file itself. Is more like a google spreadsheet or google document than a jpg or dwg file.  Is it possible to integrate with google drive and do some actions from drive interface, like delete, share or rename, making drive call my application? If no, are there any plans to do this kind of integration?

Cheers,

Mael

Answer (score 1):

Check the Google Drive SDK to integrate your app with Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/

The Java sample app is also running on App Engine: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java

Answer (score 0):

is this http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/ what you are looking for?
the gdata to connect other google services?
the "Google Documents List Data API" might be what you are after.